# Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

Tags: flutter

Estoy intentando que al momento de seleccionar una opcion de la lista del DropdownButton, en vez de guardar este valor seleccionado se guarde otro, obviamente hago la validacion para cambiar el valor, por ejemplo, si en el dropdown tengo la opcion "Masculino", hago una validacion para que este valor se cambie a 1, a lo que hago esta validacion el valor si se guarda como tal, pero a lo que paso de pagina me bota el siguiente error:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 1. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1478 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es que al usuario se le muestre una opción e internamente tenga otro valor?

Comment: Lo que queria hacer es que al momento que el usuario selecciona una opcion de la lista un ejemplo sencillo seria: Sexo = ['Masculino', 'Femenino'], si el usuario selecciona Masculino, esto se guardaria en una variable, luego lo que hice fue validar este valor y dependiendo de lo que escogiera se iba a guardar en la base de datos con un 1 o 2, no era tan complicado

Comment: así es puedes mostrar un valor y se seleccione otro para almacenar o utilizar como lo desees, no es tan complicado cuando se comprende, por lo que recomiendo que por favor publiques tu respuesta de la solución, de esta manera ayudas a otros con problemas similares y no olvides marcarla como respuesta correcta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya solucione el inconveniente que tenia, lo que trataba de hacer es que al momento de seleccionar un valor del Dropdown un ejemplo seria Sexo = "Masculino", si yo seleccionaba este lo que trataba de hace es reemplazar ese valor con otra variable, cosa que lo pude conseguir de manera sencilla, adjunto el codigo:

```
String _estadoActualS;
String valueSexo

Widget campoSexo() {
    final Responsive responsive = Responsive.of(context);
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      width: responsive.wp(95),
      child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
        hint: Text(
          "SEXO",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
        iconEnabledColor: Colors.black,
        value: _estadoActualS,
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            _estadoActualS = newValue;
           
          });
        },
        items: <String>[
          "Masculino",
          "Femenino",
        ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(
              value,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Para solucionar lo que hice fue un if para ver cual estaba seleccionado, como en esta lista solo tengo 2 valores "masculino" y "femenino", solo valide el "Masculino".

```
if (_estadoActualS == "Masculino") {
      setState(() {
        valueSexo = "1";
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        valueSexo = "2";
      });
    }
```

Y lo que hago aqui en vez de mandar la variable "_estadoActualS" a guardar en la base de datos, lo que hago es mandar la nueva variable "valueSexo".

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo manejo de esta forma, espero te sirva:

//Declaracion

List _lstfrecuencia =

["Minuto","Hora(s)","Dia(s)","Semana(s)","Mes(es)","Año"];

// desarrollo del widget

```
child: DropdownButton(
   elevation: 6,
   dropdownColor: Colors.white,
   icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
   underline: SizedBox(),                    
   iconSize: 30,
   style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black),
   items: _lstfrecuencia.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
   return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
       value: dropDownStringItem,
       child: Text(dropDownStringItem,
       style: TextStyle(fontSize:16.0),), );
   }).toList() , 
   onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
         setState(() {
            this._currentItemSeleted = newValueSelected;
          });
      },
       value: _currentItemSeleted,
       ),
    ),
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione amigo, la verdad era tan facil como validar el valor de la variable(Dropdown) y luego guardar este valor en una variable nueva y enviarla a la base de datos